# Clasping arms when cold: how does one say that?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, idioms

How does one say in English when, as a reaction to cold, a person crosses their arms, grabbing their own shoulders? It is a very common gesture, not shrugging as "I don't care", but to keep the cold off.
I believe there is one verb, but I can't remember it.

Comment: do you mean, the verb- cuddle?

Comment: @adityasrivastav I don't think so. Cuddling is what one person does to another. Hugging oneself (maybe/maybe not the right phrase) is what you do to keep yourself warm.

Comment: Yes, I mean what one does to himself for warmth.

Answer (score 4):

*Hugging oneself for warmth* comes to mind

Have a look at [Google Books](http://goo.gl/sizOzH)

Answer (score -1):

You might be thinking of **huddle** (not cuddle). While this is usually used for a group ("huddled together for warmth"), it can also be applied to individuals "huddled miserably in his greatcoat".